# How can I lists all the products according to their foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on my first eshop website using django framework and I got stuck on a problem.
I have created a general model for different kinds of products (like laptops, books etc.). Each product that is added to the website can be found by on its foreign key that links that product to a specific category.

The question is how can I display on laptops.html only the products that have the foreign key which points to the right category? Like, to display only the products from laptops category.
Thank you very much for your time!

EDIT:
in urls:

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('ComputerScience/', views.ComputerScience.as_view(), name='computer_science'),
    path('category/<int:category_pk>/list-products/', views.CompSProd.as_view(), name='category_products_list')]
```

In computerscience.html I render all the cateogries.
Here in views.py I have the two controllers, first for categories and second for laptops for instance.

views.py

```
class ComputerScience(ListView):
    model = ComputerScienceCategory
    template_name = "computer_science.html"
    context_object_name = "category"

class CompSProd(ListView):
    model = ComputerScienceProducts
    template_name = "laptops.html"
    context_object_name = "products"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        # If you wish to still keep the view only for specific category use below line
        category = get_object_or_404(ComputerScienceCategory, pk=self.kwargs.get('category_pk'))
        queryset = queryset.filter(category=category)
        return queryset
```

Here I have the template where I want to display all categories.

computer_science.html

```
<div class="computerScienceContent" id="slide">
    {% for cat in category %}
        <a href="{% url 'category_products_list' category.pk %} " id="aBar">
                <div>
                    <h4 class="cSh">{{ cat.name }}</h4>
                    <img src="{{ cat.img.url }}" alt="image" class="img">
                </div>
            </a>
    {% endfor %}
```

Here is laptops html, where I'd like to have the whole products displayed.

```
laptops.html
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block title %}
    <title>Laptops</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block cont2 %}
  
{% endblock %}
```

My main goal is that to have a page (computerscience.html) where I have displayed a list with all available categories and when you click on one category, to redirect you to another page where you have listed all the products that belongs to that category.

This is the error that has been thrown to me:

```
Reverse for 'category_products_list' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<category_pk>[0-9]+)/list\\-products/$']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `get_queryset` to filter your objects. Also as you are writing a view for a specific instance of category you would end up writing a lot of views, also when a new category would be added this would be very tedious you should use one view for all categories instead. Try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class CompSProd(ListView):
    model = ComputerScienceProducts
    template_name = "laptops.html"
    context_object_name = "products"
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        category = get_object_or_404(ComputerScienceCategory, pk=self.kwargs.get('category_pk')) # Assuming category_pk will be passed in url
        # If you wish to still keep the view only for specific category use below line
        # category = get_object_or_404(ComputerScienceCategory, pk=<pk-of-category-here>)
        queryset = queryset.filter(category=category)
        return queryset
```

To pass the categories primary key in the url you need to do something as follows:
In your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('category/<int:category_pk>/list-products/', views.CompSProd.as_view(), name='category_products_list'),
    ...
]
```

Now in the page where you display all categories:

```
{% for cat in category %}
    <a href="{% url 'category_products_list' cat.pk %}" id="aBar">
        <div>
            <h4 class="cSh">{{ cat.name }}</h4>
            <img src="{{ cat.img.url }}" alt="image" class="img">
        </div>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Also you write `id="aBar"` but this line is in a loop meaning you would end up with multiple same ids you should use a class instead.

Comment: How can I pass the category pk in the url for laptops.html ? I mean, isn't it going to take the pk for the current laptop from the database? Indeed, this way is way more profficient, as I do not have to create 4 differents views for 4 differents categories.

Comment: @tudor.il I have edited my answer, do check.

Comment: I tried your code, but it throws me this error: Reverse for 'category_products_list' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['laptop/(?P<category_pk>[0-9]+)/$'. I tried to follow your logic, but I guess I am mistaking somewhere and I cannot figure out. :(

Comment: @tudor.il The empty string likely means you are using a non existent variable i.e. something like `{% url 'category_products_list' this_variable_does_not_exist %}`. You have a list view for categories right? inside it something like this should do: `{% for cat in category %}` then inside that loop `<a href="{% url 'category_products_list' cat.pk %}">{{ cat.name }}</a>`. (You should use `categories` instead of `category` to indicate plural by the way)

Comment: So indeed, I have a template where I render the whole categories. in there, a placed the iterator. in urls, I copy pasted your url and in views.py as I wrote exactly the first  piece of code. It still does not work.  In the category.html (the template where I render the cateogires, I named the context_object_name as category. I have items stored in database, something I miss and I cannot figure it out.. but thanks a lot for your heelp. I will try harder !

Comment: @tudor.il Edit your question with what you are trying (the other template) I will take a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228895/discussion-between-tudor-il-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you so much Abdul! All the best ! :D